# how to do preg_replace_all in java

Tags: java, regex

I have wsdl file with url scattered all over it and I like to replace part of the url with something else where ever it occurs

For example here is a portion of the wsdl file

```xml
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://local.host/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="DatixInterface" targetNamespace="http://local.host/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php">
```

I like to replace all "http://local.host/web/test/11" with "http://web.server/" so it look like this

```xml
<definitions xmlns:tns="http://web.server/soap/testserver.php" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="DatixInterface" targetNamespace="http://web.server/soap/testserver.php">
```

I can easily do this using preg_replace_all in php however i can't seem to be able to do it in java.

(my primary language is not java so sorry in advance)

Any help is much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Couldn't you do a "Find and Replace" in whatever text editor you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using a simple text editor.

However you could also use **sed**, **awk** or **perl**. You can check sed examples here:
http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html

Using sed you can do:

```
sed -i .bak 's#http://local.host/web/test/11#http://web.server/#' yourfile.wsdl
```

In case of **java**, you can do this easily with a simple string.replace:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "<definitions xmlns:tns=\"http://local.host/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soapenc=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" name=\"DatixInterface\" targetNamespace=\"http://local.host/web/test/11/soap/testserver.php\">";

        String str = sentence.replaceAll("http://local.host/web/test/11", "http://web.server/");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Btw, if you want to load the content of a file and replace those strings you can use the good friend **Apache commons**:

```
File file = new File("D:\\yourfile.wsdl");
String fileString = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
String finalString = fileString.replaceAll("http://local.host/web/test/11", "http://web.server/");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, finalString);
```

Comment: thanks for this however i like to replace part of the url anything after "/soap" because i might have http://local.host/web/test/9.3 or http://local.host/web/test/10 or http://local.host/web/test/12

Comment: @MizanurRahman you can replace the whatever text you want by the content you want to. I put in the example what you said for `I like to replace all "http://local.host/web/test/11" with "http://web.server/"`

Comment: sorry, you are right - having a blond moment - thank you

Comment: @MizanurRahman lol no worries. If my answer answered to your question you might consider marking your question as resolved :)